# How to add a CssClass to the current displayed month in ASP.Net Calendar webcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, webforms, web-controls

I am currently working on implementing an ASP.Net calendar (`system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar`) into a design which requires me to add a class to the displayed month in the title. To be specific, the rendered code today is:

```
<tr>
    <td>[Previous navigation link goes here]</td>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>[Next navigation link goes here]</td>
</tr>
```

What I would like to have is:

```
<tr>
    <td>[Previous navigation link goes here]</td>
    <td class="CustomCssClass">August</td>
    <td>[Next navigation link goes here]</td>
</tr>
```

Is this possible? I have not found any property which solves my problem nor have I had any success in fetching the actual HTML server control.

Thanks in advance,
David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about the ASPNet AjaxToolKit Calendar Control:

The relevant class for the header is "`ajax__calendar_header`". You override this class in your css.

```
.ajax__calendar_header { background-color: yellow !important; }
```

**Edit**: after op comments:

Using the server control, there is a property called `TitleStyle`. You can specify your formatting here. Alternatively, you can use the property `TitleStyle-CssClass` to apply a css class to the header.

```
<asp:Calendar ID="cal" runat="server" TitleStyle-CssClass="cssclass"></asp:Calendar>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hm, may have forgotten to mention that. Nope I am using the webcontrol `system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar`.

Comment: There is a property called `TitleStyle`. Can this property suffice your requirement of styling, or do you have to necessarily apply a css class?

Comment: Yeah I have tried that one with no success since that only styles the surrounding elements, not the individual td-elements. The thing is that the design was made by an advertising agency so I cannot really change the css files either.

Comment: The problem is the server-side control does not spit pre-defined classes on each part of the calendar. Plain table. Using the `TitleStyle-CssClass` property you can style the entire `<tr>`, including the arrows. Another option is to create a new control inheriting from the calendar and then changing the html which it spits out. But, that is going to be an overkill. I have update the answer.

Comment: Yes that would be an overkill by far. I will send back the design to the agency so they change in the css from `tr > td.CssClass` to `tr.CssClass > td:nth-child(2)` or something like that, it should do the trick.